# how to change the background svg assigned settings?

Tags: jquery, html, svg

```
<html>
<body>
            <div class="box1">
              </div>
              <div class="box2">
              </div>
    <div><svg xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 300 200'>  <rect id='play' class='bar' x='20' y='60' width='80' height='120'><set attributeName='fill' to='#ec008c' begin='play.mouseover' end='play.mouseout'></set></rect></svg>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

    <style>
        .box1{
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #222;
        }
        .box2{
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #222;
        background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 300 200'><rect id='play' class='bar' x='20' y='60' width='80' height='120'><set attributeName='fill' to='#ec008c' begin='play.mouseover' end='play.mouseout'></set></rect></svg>");
        }

    </style> 
<script> 
        var bg = "url(\"data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 300 200'>  <rect id='play' class='bar' x='20' y='60' width='80' height='120'>    <set attributeName='fill' to='#ec008c' begin='play.mouseover' end='play.mouseout'></set></rect></svg>\")";

        $('.box1').css('background-image', bg );
</script>
```

Svg hover unscheduled
But the hover does not work when svg backroun
How can I change the background SVG settings with Jquery?
(Box1 background svg change)
(sorry google traslate)

Comment: Neither URL is valid because the # characters are unencoded. On top of that images are not interactive so SMIL triggered by mouseover will not work.

Comment: This article may help you understand what you have to do in order to be able to use SVG as a background image: [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris)

Comment: but this way the hover feature is not working
-svg will be assigned as background
- must be the background svg hover feature
thanks for the answers